# The difference between Find and Any for Attached entity

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have a function that get a `Book` entity, and checks whether it already exists in the database.
If it already exists, the function needs to update the entity in context.

So when I use the `Find` function to check whether it exists, the following error is thrown:

> Attaching an entity of type 'Books' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

But when I use the `Any` function to check that, the code work fine.

My guess is that the `Find` function Attach the entity (to context) but `Any` not doing it.

Can someone give an explanation please?

The `Find` function:

```cs
public IHttpActionResult PutBook(Books book)
{
    if(db.Books.Find(book.id) == null)
    {
        db.Entry(book).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    .
    .
}
```

The `Any` function:

```cs
public IHttpActionResult PutBook(Books book)
{
    if (db.Books.Any(b => b.id.Equals(book.id)))
    {
        db.Entry(book).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    .
    .
}
```

Sorry if I have English errors.

Comment: Could you please update your post. For instance, `db.Categories` probably is `db.Books`? And both code snippets are exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `Find` fetches an entity from the database and attaches it to the context if it's not already in its cache. So at that point there is a `Book` instance in the context's cache and then you try to attach *another* instance to it. That's not allowed, because EF's cache is designed as an [identity map](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html).

The second snippet obviously doesn't materialize a `Book` instance: it runs a SQL query that only returns a `bool`.